# android blogger post with image

Tags: android, blogger

I am trying to build an android application that allows me to post to Blogger with an image.

I can successfully post with an image already hosted online.  However, using the google API uploading an images has been unsuccessful.

```
Could not find class 'com.google.gdata.data.media.MediaStreamSource', referenced from method com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.getMediaResource

unable to resolve new-instance 2941 (Lcom/google/gdata/data/media/MediaStreamSource;) in Lcom/google/gdata/client/media/MediaService;

replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0013

Failed resolving Lcom/google/gdata/data/media/MediaSource; interface 4084 'Ljavax/activation/DataSource;'
Link of class 'Lcom/google/gdata/data/media/MediaSource;' failed
```

code:

```
PicasawebService oPicasaWebService = new PicasawebService("example");
    try {
         oPicasaWebService.setUserCredentials("AAA@gmail.com", "AAA");
        } catch
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click in Project > properties > Java build PAth > order and export

have you checked all external libraries (picasa, google, etc)?